# FTSearch in Domino not working for Domino 851 server however it works fine for Domino 8

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I have two Domino servers one having the version Domino 8 and the other having Domino 851. FTSearch API works fine with Domino 8 server(French server) and doesn't work fine with the Domino 851.

The query is like "[_CreationDate]  >= 1/1/2009". Date formats are handled well to generate the date in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. FTSearch API always returns 0(ZERO) when a query is made with the above said query. However there are messages in the domino server which are later 1/1/2009.

System.out.println("DOMINO" + unFilteredView.getName());//($Inbox)
retCount = unFilteredView.FTSearch(query,0);
Code is in JAVA.

Date search works fine in Domino851 if the messages in the server are full text indexed. However if messages are not indexed in the Domino 851, then search in it doesn't work.

The error displayed in the Domino Server console is "full text operations on database mail\tuser.nsf which is not fully indexed. This is extremele inefficient"

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks,
Rajath.

Answer (score 3):

The error message states, that you are calling a full text operation on a server, where there is no full text index for the database enabled.

As the FTI is a per database, per server setting, you have to enable it on all replicas of a database explicitly.

Create/Enable the full text index on the Domino 8.5.1 server and the code will work.

Best practice would be to use the `Database.IsFTIndexed` property of the Database class to check for an existing FTIndex, before you call the FT method.